# Very poor performance after dismissViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller that presents another one modally which contains a gif and a table view with animation on the cells, and when I dismiss it, the app has an annoyingly long delay before you can do anything again (like 3-5 seconds).

I've found answers that say it's because I still have a reference to the vc after its dismissal, but I don't see how that's possible because the only place I make a reference to it is in prepareForSegue.

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1:**

Here is my `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! InWorkoutViewController
    destVC.workout = workout
}
```

The destVC's workout property is an optional custom class.

**Edit 2:**

Here is how the VC is dismissed (still very slow):

```
@IBAction func tappedX(sender: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [unowned self] in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Comment: Add your `prepareForSegue` code to the question. Show how properties in the destination VC that receive data in `prepareForSegue` are defined.

Comment: No, those other answers weren't asking whether view controller A had some other references to view controller B, but rather view controller B had some circular set of references back to itself (a.k.a. strong reference cycle). Given that the problem goes away after 3-5 seconds, that might be a red herring, though. I'd focus on what is blocking the UI for 3-5 seconds. I'd also make sure you're not updating any UI from a background thread. Unfortunately, we can't diagnose anything without some code, or at least some description of the type of actions you are performing.

Comment: Thanks for that @Rob, I'm not sure you want me to post my entire two files, are there any specific functions I should post?

Comment: Essentially the vc being presented animates a gif, and has a table view where once cell at a time is performing an animation

Comment: Assuming there's a ton of nasty code, no, we don't want to see all of it. Your goal is to post the smallest possible reproducible example (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). So, identify what the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. But the animation sounds suspicious. I'd start there.

Comment: To create MCVE, there are two approaches: You can copy your project somewhere and start ripping out the irrelevant stuff until you'd left with only that code that's causing the problem. Or approach it the other way, start blank project and add relevant bits of your code into it until the problem manifests itself again. BTW, invariably, in this exercise of creating the MCVE, you will identify the source of the problem and you'll probably be able to fix it yourself. But if not, post just the bit of code you added that caused the problem to start to manifest itself.

Comment: How are you animating the `gif` - could these animations be blocking the main thread? How are you dismissing the view controller (are you dismissing on a background thread)?

Comment: You've shared your `prepareForSegue`, but that's unlikely to be the source of the problem. It's likely your animation. Or possibly you're initiating some UI stuff from a background thread. Or you have some code that is blocking the main thread (e.g. performing some synchronous network request). You need to narrow it down by removing parts of the code and see when the problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm away from my code atm but I'm using a library for the gif to animate it and when I dismiss I stop both that animation and the table view cell animation first. I think robotic cat nailed the problem, gonna try dismissing on the main thread when I can.